# Looking for help migrating AWS Beanstalk Service to another account

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, flask-migrate

Seeking help migrating AWS Beanstalk to another account.

I am a part of an AWS org where I deployed an AWS Beanstalk Service in early June under my account. My internship with them has expired, and I need to get this service off my account now, and exit the org. I am unsure how to transfer the service to theirs. This is an AWS Beanstalk Service, with RDS (postgreSQL) and S3 enabled and all the additional pre-configured service (EC2/load balancing..etc.). I am happy to provide all necessary details around tech stack and aws configs.

Can anyone provide guidance? I checked the official doc: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-migration-accounts but I found it not helpful.

I am under the impression that I need to save the configuration, download it and then upload this on their account in s3 to restore it. As you know AWS is not that straight forward. I would love some guidance here.

Initial Questions:

1. What is the best way to transfer this service to theirs?
2. If they create an IAM user for me. Can I log in- create a new beanstalk service and upload my saved configuration?
3. Should I request access to their root account and just re-configure from the start?
4. Is there a way to directly transfer ownership?

Thank you!

Comment: Contact someone on your team that has the necessary experience. Stuff like this cannot be covered in an answer or article, it requires individual hands on explanation and steps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no an easy way of doing what you want. What I'd do is to use Terraform to manage all the resources (you can import existing resources to Terraform) and after that apply that to the other account. As to the DB data you can create backups to S3 and replicate it to the other account's S3. The same goes for the existing S3 data.
That's why we need to use IaC whenever is possible.